# How to get values from Step Counter without any events?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am writing an app and I need to get Step Counters value at the start of the app. I don't need to wait for the first step to be made. I want it right at the start. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125862/5255006

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya it is not similar in any case. 1) it's old and doesn't even use Step Counter 2) I know how to count steps. I need a result in `onStart()`